# why Break is not Breaking out of loop for this small piece of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop, break

List item

```
# To put values in list till user want
#comparing value entered with the ascii value ofenter
# key , if enter then come out of infinite loop
# why break is not breaking out on enter press
#if value is not enter_key thn put this value in list
x=1
lis=[]
while x == 1 :
    var = str(input())
    if var == chr(10):  
        break                     
    lis.append(var)    

print("i m free now from infinite loop")
print(lis)
```

Comment: Because if the user just hits enter the result is an empty string, not the line feed character. Also the result of input is already a string.

Comment: why are you comparing to `chr(10)`??? Have you actually looked at what is returned by simply pressing enter when prompted by `input`?

Comment: The `str` in `str(input())` is redundant. `input()` returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user presses the enter key without entering anything when prompted by `str(input())`, then the return value will be an empty string. Thus, you shouldn't be comparing `var` to `chr(10)`, which is the newline character (`\n`). Instead try this:

```
x=1
lis=[]
while x == 1 :
    var = str(input())
    if var == "":            #Compare to an empty string!
        break                     
    lis.append(var)    

print("i m free now from infinite loop")
print(lis)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what the user wants is to stop on an empty string. So I would make the code as follows

```
a_list=[]

while True :
    var = input('What is your input: ')
    if not var:
        break
    a_list.append(var)

print("I'm free now from the infinite loop")
print(a_list)
```

Comment: input already returns a string, no need to `str(input(....))` and `if not var:break` would serve the same purpose as empty strings are falsy - see [falsy truthy python values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)